# UIApplication sharedApplication EXC BAD ACCESS in a UITextField category

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, objective-c-category, uiapplication

```
- (void)someMethod
{
BOOL isRightToLeft = ([UIApplication sharedApplication].userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft)
}
```

This causes exc bad access. I'm thinking its because its not thread safe and its called many times. What are the rules in using uiapplication sharedApplication? Thanks!

Comment: I know you think this causes the exe. bad access, but could you post the stack trace associated with the crash as well?

Comment: You can do this by [setting an exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode) or running in the simulator.

Comment: What I did is I created a SOMETextField and instead of putting -somemethod in the category of UITextField, I placed it in the category of SOMETextField. I need to move on now from this. Thanks guys for all the help!